# Java open web page through user's default browser

Tags: java

I know that i can use

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI());
```

to open web page through user's default browser, BUT

every time i open web page it'll open in a new tab.

Do you have any idea if i want to make it opens in only the "same tab".

Comment: It depends on the user's browser settings. The **user** controls the "open in" behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
new URI("javascript:window.open('www.google.de','unique')");
```